# Image in <img> tag is defaulting to 0 x 0 pixels despite setting its size

Tags: css, html, image, html5-video

For some reason I'm unable to set the image size when using an `<img>` tag inside an **html5** `video` element.  It is always defaulting back to **0 x 0 pixels**.

The reason I'm using this `img` is as a fallback for ancient browsers where the video tag just will not work.

Here's my code **NOTE I have deliberately removed "myVideo.mp4" to mimic the fallback** :

```
<video id="welcome" height="1080" width="1920" preload="auto" loop autoplay>
   <source type="video/mp4" src="@Url.Content("~/_video/myVideo.mp4")" />
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/_video/posterframe.jpg")" height="1080" width="1920"/>
</video>
```

This produces the following result (when debugging in chrome). Note the **"0x0 pixels (Natural: 1920 x 1080)"**

[image: 0 pixels]

Does anyone have any suggests as to a fix? Thanks v much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the browser's way of hiding the `<img>` since the `<video>` element *is* supported in Chrome. If you open this in IE8 for example, the *fallback* `<img>` content is displayed correctly.

The conditions you have used to test the fallback are incorrect. Removing the video source will simply result in the browser not finding the content (i.e. a 404). In this case, the correct fallback is to use the `poster=""` attribute on the [`<video>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/video.html) element, which is not in your markup.

> **poster**
>
> The address of an image file for the UA to show while no video data is available

For example:

```
<video poster="@Url.Content("~/_video/posterframe.jpg")" id="welcome" height="150" width="150" preload="auto" loop autoplay>
   <source type="video/mp4" src="@Url.Content("~/_video/myVideo.mp4")" />
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/_video/posterframe.jpg")" height="1080" width="1920"/>
</video>
```

**Full Demo** (working for me in Chrome 26)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>HTML5 video demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="welcome" height="150" width="100" preload="auto" loop autoplay poster="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/abstract/1/">
   <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.808.dk/pics/video/gizmo.mp4" />
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/abstract/1/" height="150" width="100" alt="" title="Your browser does not support the <video> tag"/>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh great shout about the fallback condition (+1 thanks!).  But okay, so I didn't explain the full story... The reason I've excluded `poster` from the `<video>` element is that as soon as I included it chrome stopped supporting my video!  I have no idea why, but as soon as I included `poster` the video would not play.

Comment: Can you add the generated HTML to your question please? I have a demo running locally that works as expected - poster shown if video not available.

Comment: I've created a http://jsfiddle.net/PaUzS/ with my code but this seems to be working!  Maybe it's an MVC issue, or something to do with my body tags and background image I use

Comment: By the way I'll accept your answer because you have actually answered the question I asked... I've just 'moved the goal posts' since!

Comment: Yes, your fiddle also works for me. Does your page [validate](http://validator.w3.org/)?