# 0 x 0 pixels: html doesn't apply their proper dimensions

Tags: html, css, image, nivo-slider

I don't know why, but the browser thinks that the images must be "shown" with **0 x 0** pixels resolution. Nevertheless the browser actually does know that, let's say "promotoras-1.jpg", has a resolution of 800 x 600.

I saw this question ([Image in <img> tag is defaulting to 0 x 0 pixels despite setting its size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603564/image-in-img-tag-is-defaulting-to-0-x-0-pixels-despite-setting-its-size)) but that's not exactly my case (I'm not using a HTML5 video tag here).

[image]

**Is there a way to fix that?**

### EDIT:

I didn't set any `height` or `width` for the images. But I'm using both, **Lightbox** and **Nivo-Slider** together. It worked for me before, but then this happened. I've tried deactivating the scripts, and also played with the inspector with the properties, deactivating all of them, just to see if the images would still show up... but it's still the same result.

### EDIT 2: [Link to the site](http://www.showsparaeventos.com/produccion/Carpas+y+gazebos)

Comment: 1) Select the element in the DOM 2) trace styles 3)? 4) profit!

Comment: Can you show a jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you see the source of the styles in developer tools?

Comment: [Here's the link to the site](http://www.showsparaeventos.com/produccion/Carpas+y+gazebos), use the inspector. Note that if you remove one `img` out of the `#imagen` div, the image shows up. I didn't apply any CSS to `#imagen` that makes img go 0x0, which makes it weird.

Comment: Path is: #big_wrapper > #middle > #mid > #imagen > .slider-wrapper theme-dark > #slider > (the images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I've found the mistake: I didn't call the function `nivoSlider();`.

Also make sure that the jQuery version you're running isn't below 1.9.1

Comment: Also I'm leaving this note for those who use Dropbox: don't get cocky with the program (if you see the copy conflict thing). Just pay attention (carefully) when checking which is the latest one edited, then you erase the rest of the copies.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's some style that's modifying that image, something like:

```
height: 0;
width: 0;
```

I see you are using a lightbox plugin. Maybe is that plugin that is hidding the image using css or js. Are you using correctly that plugin?

Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't set any `height` or `width` for the images. But I'm using both, Lightbox and Nivo-Slider together. I'll edit the question for more info about what I did.