# Image showing 0*0 pixels in inspect element

Tags: php, html, css

i am working on some app, when i run it on firefox it works fine but when i run it on chrome it does not show all images. When i see the elements using inspect element it shows my 0 by 0 pixel(natural  330*220 pixels). Here is my code for displaying images

```
 <section id="clients" class="append-bottom">
            <div id="clients-topbar" >  
                <h3 class="append-bottom clear-left clear-right border-left center border" ><i class="icon-group grey_color"></i><span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px; vertical-align: text-bottom;"> Valued Clients</span></h3>
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" hspace="0">
        <div class="clients-list ">

            <?php 
            foreach($modelClients as $key)
            { ?>   
            <div class="clients-item">
               <?php echo CHtml::image(yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/clients/'.$key->id.'/'.$key->image,'Parking Media',array('style'=>'width:150px;'));
            ?>
            </div>

               <?php }?>          
              <?php 
            foreach($modelClients as $key)
            { ?>   
            <div class="clients-item">
               <?php echo CHtml::image(yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/clients/'.$key->id.'/'.$key->image,'Parking Media',array('style'=>' width:150px;'));
            ?>
            </div>

               <?php }?>  
              <?php 
            foreach($modelClients as $key)
            { ?>   
            <div class="clients-item">
               <?php echo CHtml::image(yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/clients/'.$key->id.'/'.$key->image,'Parking Media',array('style'=>' width:150px;'));
            ?>
            </div>

               <?php }?>  
              <?php 
            foreach($modelClients as $key)
            { ?>   
            <div class="clients-item">
               <?php echo CHtml::image(yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/clients/'.$key->id.'/'.$key->image,'Parking Media',array('style'=>' width:150px;'));
            ?>
            </div>

               <?php }?>  
              <?php 
            foreach($modelClients as $key)
            { ?>   
            <div class="clients-item">
               <?php echo CHtml::image(yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/clients/'.$key->id.'/'.$key->image,'Parking Media',array('style'=>' width:150px;'));
            ?>
            </div>

               <?php }?>  
        </div>

        </marquee>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have seen this link [Image in <img> tag is defaulting to 0 x 0 pixels despite setting its size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603564/image-in-img-tag-is-defaulting-to-0-x-0-pixels-despite-setting-its-size) but unable to resolve the issue.

**EDIT:**

```
<section id="clients" class="append-bottom">
        <div id="clients-topbar">  
            <h3 class="append-bottom clear-left clear-right border-left center border"><i class="icon-group grey_color"></i><span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px; vertical-align: text-bottom;"> Valued Clients</span></h3>
            <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" hspace="0">
            <div class="clients-list  crum_start_animation">


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style="width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/7/America.jpg" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style="width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/8/Uk.jpg" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style="width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/9/germany.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style="width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/10/russia.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style="width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/11/spain.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style="width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/12/italy.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style="width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/13/greece.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style="width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/14/hungary.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style="width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/15/norway.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style="width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/16/sweden.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>



                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/7/America.jpg" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/8/Uk.jpg" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/9/germany.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/10/russia.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/11/spain.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/12/italy.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/13/greece.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/14/hungary.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/15/norway.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/16/sweden.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>



                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/7/America.jpg" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/8/Uk.jpg" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/9/germany.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/10/russia.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/11/spain.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/12/italy.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/13/greece.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/14/hungary.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/15/norway.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/16/sweden.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>



                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/7/America.jpg" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/8/Uk.jpg" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/9/germany.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/10/russia.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/11/spain.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/12/italy.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/13/greece.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/14/hungary.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/15/norway.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/16/sweden.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>



                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/7/America.jpg" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/8/Uk.jpg" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/9/germany.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/10/russia.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/11/spain.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/12/italy.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/13/greece.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/14/hungary.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/15/norway.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


                <div class="clients-item">
                   <img style=" width:150px;" src="/allSpice_falak/images/clients/16/sweden.png" alt="Parking Media" class="crum_start_animation">                </div>


            </div>

            </marquee>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Could you posts your generated html instead of your php?

Comment: Does the image exist?  If it doesn't I think chrome just displays the alt text - if there is no alt text then it will display nothing

Comment: yes image exists, i tried it opening in new tab and it opened perfectly. I dont know is it right to post the link to website but apologies if it is forbidden at SO. Here is my website link http://falaktextile.allspicetech.com

Comment: awkward thing is that first 5 images are diplayed fine, rest does not show right.

Comment: Maybe making image "Display: block" makes the width:150px work?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see now how you use the `<Marquee>` tag (No idea that was still around after everything and everybody uses jQuery :D)...

But the fix seems to be to remove the `max-width:100%` from the `img{}` in your css-file, i that fixed it for me. No idea why btw! :D

Comment: you are on spot but i wrote 20% in "client list" css class. Now when i removed that, all images have become very small(not desirable). secondly marquee was easy to implement when client was on my neck. lol.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since this was posted but I ran into the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Add the desired width size as the max-width and set the width of the image element to 100% as so;

```
img{
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
```